# Vue cant watch object property setted inside for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to set a object property inside a `for`-loop, and watch for those changes, but somehow Vue simply doesn't listen to all changes on the `watch` prop.

Here is my test code to simplify my issue (https://jsfiddle.net/hn2wepc9/).

If you click on the button, it should log 5 lines in the console (because of the `loop` method), but it only logs 1. I don't understand why Vue simply doesnt listen to all changes when I use `Vue.set()` inside a `for` loop and try to watch these changes.

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="loop">Button</button>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
          obj: {
            name: 'John Doe'
        }
     }
  },
  methods: {
    loop() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Vue.set(this.obj, 'name', 'Dohn Joe ' + i);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    obj: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        window.console.log(newVal.name + ' - ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use `Vue.set` here since `obj.name` already exists at init in `data()`. That could just be set directly: `this.obj.name = 'Dohn Joe ' + i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, watchers are run asynchronously (in the *next* macro tick) as a performance optimization. I think the motivation is watchers are assumed to only care about the most recent change.

You can configure the watcher to be synchronous by setting the `sync` flag (one of several [undocumented `watch` flags](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/4f111f9/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L59-L63)):

```js
watch: {
  obj: {
    sync: true
  }
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ab8mgr6/)

---

For reference, in Vue 3, the flag is called `flush` with `pre`, `post`, and `sync` as possible values. See [Effect flush timing](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#effect-flush-timing).

Comment: Is this in Vue docs? I read the docs and just didn't find nothing about `sync` prop. Thank you so much.

Comment: No, it's one of [several undocumented flags](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/4f111f9/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L59-L63).

Comment: Just a comment here that I just found, seems that sync api is not public according this post https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-difference-between-immediate-and-sync-in-watch/24408